Bug report when emmeans() is used along with fct_na_value_to_level()
This is an MRE that shows an inconsistency in the use of emmeans() along with fct_na_value_to_level().
It wasn't easy to get the why of the error from my initial code ;)
I prefer to put it here instead on GitHub because I don't know which package can fix the behavior.
What do you think?
Thank you
# I was dealing with na values in some factors and I decided to use the fct_na_value_to_level() function
warpbreaks2 <- warpbreaks |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    tension_na_value = forcats::fct_na_level_to_value(tension, "L"), # just to simulate some missing values in my datatset
    tension_na_level = forcats::fct_na_value_to_level(tension_na_value, "missing"), # I want to make the missing values explicit for my later model
    tension_na_level2 = forcats::fct_na_value_to_level(tension_na_value) # this is another try, without renaming the new explicit level
  )

# For your information
levels(warpbreaks2$tension_na_level)
#> [1] "M"       "H"       "missing"
levels(warpbreaks2$tension_na_level2)
#> [1] "M" "H" NA

# First try : everything is ok
lm(breaks ~ wool * tension_na_level, data = warpbreaks2) |> 
  emmeans::emmeans (~ wool | tension_na_level)
#> tension_na_level = M:
#>  wool emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
#>  A      24.0 3.65 48     16.7     31.3
#>  B      28.8 3.65 48     21.4     36.1
#> 
#> tension_na_level = H:
#>  wool emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
#>  A      24.6 3.65 48     17.2     31.9
#>  B      18.8 3.65 48     11.4     26.1
#> 
#> tension_na_level = missing:
#>  wool emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
#>  A      44.6 3.65 48     37.2     51.9
#>  B      28.2 3.65 48     20.9     35.6
#> 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95

# Second try throws an error. the behaviour of emmeans() is not consistant, but maybe it's an issue with how fct_na_value_to_level() is written?
lm(breaks ~ wool * tension_na_level2, data = warpbreaks2) |> 
  emmeans::emmeans (~ wool | tension_na_level2)
#> Error in X[, nm, drop = FALSE]: indice hors limites

Created on 2024-07-08 with reprex v2.1.1


Session info

sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14)
#>  os       Manjaro Linux
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  C
#>  ctype    fr_FR.UTF-8
#>  tz       Indian/Reunion
#>  date     2024-07-08
#>  pandoc   3.1.11 @ /usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/x86_64/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package      * version  date (UTC) lib source
#>  cli            3.6.3    2024-06-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  coda           0.19-4.1 2024-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  codetools      0.2-20   2024-03-31 [2] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#>  digest         0.6.36   2024-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  dplyr          1.1.4    2023-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  emmeans        1.10.3   2024-07-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#>  estimability   1.5.1    2024-05-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  evaluate       0.24.0   2024-06-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  fansi          1.0.6    2023-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  fastmap        1.2.0    2024-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  forcats        1.0.0    2023-01-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  fs             1.6.4    2024-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  generics       0.1.3    2022-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  glue           1.7.0    2024-01-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  htmltools      0.5.8.1  2024-04-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  knitr          1.48     2024-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#>  lattice        0.22-6   2024-03-20 [2] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#>  lifecycle      1.0.4    2023-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  magrittr       2.0.3    2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  MASS           7.3-61   2024-06-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  Matrix         1.7-0    2024-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  multcomp       1.4-25   2023-06-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  mvtnorm        1.2-5    2024-05-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  pillar         1.9.0    2023-03-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  pkgconfig      2.0.3    2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  R6             2.5.1    2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  reprex         2.1.1    2024-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#>  rlang          1.1.4    2024-06-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  rmarkdown      2.27     2024-05-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  rstudioapi     0.16.0   2024-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  sandwich       3.1-0    2023-12-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  sessioninfo    1.2.2    2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  survival       3.6-4    2024-04-24 [2] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#>  TH.data        1.1-2    2023-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  tibble         3.2.1    2023-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  tidyselect     1.2.1    2024-03-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  utf8           1.2.4    2023-10-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  vctrs          0.6.5    2023-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  withr          3.0.0    2024-01-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  xfun           0.45     2024-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  xtable         1.8-4    2019-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  yaml           2.3.9    2024-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#>  zoo            1.8-12   2023-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#> 
#>  [1] /home/annadoizy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.4
#>  [2] /usr/lib/R/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────


The bug is now solved, see https://github.com/rvlenth/emmeans/issues/500 for details.
The error will be no more in the next emmeans release.
Thanks to @russ

I'd say it is a bug in the emmeans package (line 81), specifically the ref_grid function, which is called by emmeans.
On line 80:
if (is.factor(x) && !(nm %in% coerced$covariates)) 
      xlev[[nm]] = levels(factor(x))

The second line above removes the NA in the levels of x since factor(x) removes level NA in x. The object xlev then does not contain the level NA anymore and the function generates an error further down the track (specifically, in the function called by emm_basis on line 11). I think line 81 above should be simply:
xlev[[nm]] = levels(x)

or perhaps
xlev[[nm]] = levels(factor(x, exclude=NULL))

But that's up to the package author to decide.

Thanks a lot! Your answer does make the issue definitely clearer! I'll make an issue to Russel Lenth in github and put here the updates.

This issue is reported on the emmeans issues page and I answered there. It is necessary to use factor(x) there in order to align the levels when the user specifies a subset of them in the at argument. So I do not think it is possible to fix this without reducing the features in the package.

Well, I seem to have been able to fix what I thought was unfixable. And I added an option to disable that fix if it causes problems. See issue #500.
